# How to flip coord data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I currently have two sets of coords data, one of which I want to flip, and the other I would like to remain the same, and then plot both of these on the same plot.

I want to flip the away team coords, so not both of the plots are on the same side of the pitch when I plot both of them.

```html
#home team coords
x_coords_h = ([float((k['X'])) * 124.5 for k in data['h']])
y_coords_h = ([float((k['Y'])) * 80 for k in data['h']])
coords_h = ([(float(k['X']) * 124.5, float(k['Y']) * 80) for k in data['h']])

#away team coords
x_coords_a = ([float((k['X'])) * 124.5 for k in data['a']])
y_coords_a = ([float((k['Y'])) * 80 for k in data['a']])
coords_a = ([(float(k['X']) * 124.5, float(k['Y']) * 80) for k in data['a']])

#plot shots

#plot home shots
#ax.scatter(x_coords_h, y_coords_h, c = "blue", label = 'shots')

#plot away shots
ax.scatter(x_coords_a, y_coords_a, c = "red", label = 'shots')


plt.ylim(0, 80)
plt.xlim(0, 120)
plt.text(95, 5, "@Jack_Nesbitt", color="#f7f7f7", fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

The aim is to get the two below outputs, overlaying (I got this by using ax.invert_yaxis() & ax.invert_xaxis() but this won't work for using two sets of data from what I know):

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `invert_xaxis`:

Look at this MCVE:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([.2,.4],[.2,.4],c='blue')
ax1 = ax.twiny()
ax1.invert_xaxis()
ax1.scatter([.2,.4],[.2,.4],c='red')
```

Output:

[image]